# python variable unpacking fails

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, string-formatting, argument-unpacking

7.10 and for some reason the following code snippet is producing an error...

```
device_info = {'username': 'test', 'password': 'test', 'appliance': 'name', 'hostname': 'hostname', 'prodcut': 'juice'}
print "{} {} {} {} {}".format(**device_info)
```

This raises an exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 4, in <module>
    print "{} {} {} {} {}".format(**device_info)
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

I believe this code should be syntactically sound, however, I don't seem to be able to unpack my dict to pass to any functions, not sure why that doesn't work.

Comment: What is the expected output? The first `*` will just put the keys in there, so the second `*` is going to cause a syntax error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing in your fields as keyword arguments, because you are using `**` syntax:

```
"....".format(**device_info)
#             ^^
```

Your placeholders, however, specifically only work with *positional* arguments; placeholders without any name or index, are automatically numbered:

```
"{} {} {} {} {}".format(...)
# ^0 ^1 ^2 ^3 ^4
```

This is why you get an index error, there is no positional argument with index 0. Keyword arguments have no index, because they are essentially key-value pairs in a dictionary, which are unordered structures.

If you wanted to include the values from the dictionary into a string, then you need to explicitly name your placeholders:

```
"{username} {password} {appliance} {hostname} {prodcut}".format(**device_info)
```

(but note the misspelling of *product* as *prodcut*, you may want to check if your dictionary keys are spelled correctly).

You'd get all the values inserted in the named slots:

```
>>> print "{username} {password} {appliance} {hostname} {prodcut}".format(**device_info)
test test name hostname juice
```

If you expected the *keys* to be printed, then you'd have to pass in the `device_info` keys as separate positional arguments; `"...".format(*device_info)` (single `*`) would do just that, but then you'd also have to content with the ['arbitrary' dictionary order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15479928/why-is-the-order-in-dictionaries-and-sets-arbitrary) that the keys would be listed in.

Answer (score -1):

device_info = {'username': 'test', 'password': 'test', 'appliance': 'name', 'hostname': 'hostname', 'prodcut': 'juice'}

print ("{username} {password}  {appliance} {hostname} {prodcut}".format(**device_info))